# Error when creating a batch job in Oracle: already exists?

Tags: database, oracle, jobs

I am trying to create a job in my Oracle database to refresh a materialized view every five minutes. The following is the code I have made:

```
BEGIN
SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job(
    job_name => 'refresh_cop_union',
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action => 'BEGIN DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH(''COP_UNION'',''C''); END;',
    start_date => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    repeat_interval => 'freq=minutely;interval=5',
    end_date => NULL,
    enabled => TRUE,
    auto_drop => FALSE,
    comments => 'Refresh COP_UNION matview'
);
END;
/
```

When I executed it I got the following error:

> Error report - 
>   ORA-27477: "MASTER_DB"."REFRESH_COP_UNION" already exists 
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 175 
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 288 
>   ORA-06512: at line 2 
>   27477. 00000 -  "\"%s\".\"%s\" already exists" 
>   *Cause:    An attempt was made to create an object with a name that has
>              already been used by another object in the same schema. 
>   *Action:   Reissue the command using a different name or schema.

So it seems I have another object in my database with the same name, probably another job. Therefore I tried to execute the following code to delete it and replace it with my new version:

```
BEGIN
  sys.dbms_scheduler.drop_job(job_name => 'refresh_cop_union');
END;
/
```

But it failed with the following error:

> Error report - 
>   ORA-27475: unknown job "MASTER_DB"."REFRESH_COP_UNION" 
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 274 
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 753 
>   ORA-06512: at line 2 
>   27475. 00000 -  "unknown %s \"%s\".\"%s\"" 
>   *Cause:    The specified object did not exist, privileges were not granted,
>              or the object was of the wrong type. 
>   *Action:   Specify an object of the correct type on which you have privileges.

Which basically says that the object I am trying to delete doesn't exist. How is this possible? How can I find this object, see what it is and eventually delete it?
I also went through all the objects that may have a similar name in my database: other tables, views, triggers but I found nothing.
I tried to list all the jobs I have in order to find mine with:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_JOBS
WHERE WHAT LIKE '%COP_UNION%';
```

But nothing showed up. Any idea?

Comment: I saw this once. It can be that the job is running and freezed. You dropped it and it is "dropped", but cannot be re-created as it is still "running" so to speak.
Try dbms_scheduler.drop_job(job_name => 'refresh_cop_union', force=>TRUE)

Comment: Thanks @MiroslavDuník for your comment, but unfortunately it didn't work. It showed up the same error you can see above. It still seems that the object doesn't exist.

Comment: Is there a way to see the names given to the jobs that are obtained by the command query `SELECT * FROM USER_JOBS`?

Comment: in my case, the error is because the job is executing, running, so one should  check `user_scheduler_running_jobs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must select `USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS` rather then `USER_JOBS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS
where JOB_NAME LIKE '%COP_UNION%';
```

`DBMS_SCHEDULER` are (new) **scheduler jobs**, whereas (old) **jobs** are maintained by package `DBMS_JOB`

Looks like a scheduler job must not have the same name as any other object. Check with

```
SELECT * 
FROM ALL_OBJECTS 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME LIKE '%COP_UNION%';
```

and chose a different name.

Seems to be a bug ([Bug 4055853](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=390732.1&id=4055853)) in Oracle. According to Oracle the solution/workaround is

> Changing the job name to be different than any object owned by the
>   user will work around the problem.

Comment: I didn't know this difference, thanks for pointing it out, but unfortunately if I execute `SELECT * FROM USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS` only three jobs shows up and none of them is named as the one I am trying to create, so the error I get is still unexplained for me.

Comment: Did you try `ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS` or even `DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS`?

Comment: Yes, still the same three jobs I mentioned before, none with the name I am looking for.

Comment: Changing the name of the job made it work. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error occurred because the job was running. One should check `USER_SCHEDULER_RUNNING_JOBS`.

```
DECLARE
  v_count NUMBER;
  v_job_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'BP_SCHEMA_STATS';
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO v_count FROM user_scheduler_running_jobs WHERE job_name = v_job_name;
  IF v_count = 1 THEN
    NULL; -- job is running
  ELSE
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
     JOB_NAME             => v_job_name,
     JOB_TYPE             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
     JOB_ACTION           => 'BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(SYS_CONTEXT(''USERENV'',''CURRENT_SCHEMA'')); END;',
     ENABLED              => TRUE);
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and manage to resolve it with a help from my fellow developer.
I dropped a package and then tried to reuse the same name for a dbms_scheduler job, but job creation failed with the same error ORA-27475...

Solution:

1. Run this query:

   `select * from OBJ$ where name = 'REFRESH_COP_UNION';`

   If you find any records (usually 2 rows), look for a column named TYPE#. If the value is 10, it means that the object had been dropped, but the name was left to be reused. Apparently DBMS_SCHEDULER package doesn't know how to re-use dropped package names. It's obviously an Oracle bug.
2. Workaround is to create and then drop a table with the same name:

   `create table "MASTER_DB"."REFRESH_COP_UNION" (id number);`

   `drop table "MASTER_DB"."REFRESH_COP_UNION";`

After this, job creation works without errors.
Useful link: https://gotodba.com/2018/06/28/non-existent-objects-and-possibly-a-bug/

Answer (score 0):

Issue could be due to the reason that you might have a stored procedure or function with name, `REFRESH_COP_UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

the comment by Miroslav Duník -

> I saw this once. It can be that the job is running and freezed. You
> dropped it and it is "dropped", but cannot be re-created as it is
> still "running" so to speak. Try dbms_scheduler.drop_job(job_name =>
> 'refresh_cop_union', force=>TRUE)

worked for me . Thank you :)